# Getting lux value from light sensor without onSensorChanged() event?

Tags: java, android, android-sensors

Just wondering, is there a way to gain the value of the light sensor on an Android phone without waiting for an onSensorChanged() event to occur? To save battery I use registerListener() and unregisterListener() after getting a single lux value, however the next time I register the listener to get another value, if that value is the same as before, my application sits there waiting for an event which may take a while to occur (typically in low-light situations).

So, is there a way I can read the lux value without waiting for an onSensorChanged() event? Or should I just have a 100ms timeout and then use the last value I recorded?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I also wanted to achieve the same for `accelerometer` or `compass` i.e. get the current value only without listening on to the change events and wait for any physical change to occur but after lot of search I have came to conclusion that it is not possible.

Only way to read value from these devices is to listen for events continuously.

Comment: on registration of the listener, does it return something like 'current value of light'?, without triggering a change in value